# Convert Oracle NVl QUery to Criteria Query

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

is there any way to convert this Oracle Query to Criteria Query.

```
SELECT * FROM T_MERCHANT_ORDER_DETAILS where MERCHANT_ID = in_merchantId and ORDER_ID= nvl(in_orderId,ORER_ID) and 
TRANSACTION_ID=nvl(in_txnId,TRANSACTION_ID);
```

in_merchantId and in_orderId are the variables passed to the oracle procedure.
can i do this in Hibernate.

NOTE::: it returns result set based on merchantId if orderId and txnId are null,
        or merchantId and orderId if only txnId is null,
        and on all three if no one is null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not? Just omit the predicates if orderId/tx is null and add them otherwise ... that way the nvl-functionality is moved to the java code but i don't see a problem with that in your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Did this to make it work.

```
if(orderId==null && transactionId ==null) {
        criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("merchantId"),merchantId));
    }
    else if(transactionId==null && orderId!=null) {
        criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("merchantId"),merchantId),builder.equal(root.get("orderId"),orderId));
    }
    else {
        criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("merchantId"),merchantId),builder.equal(root.get("transactionId"),transactionId));
    }
```

but i think it can be done with more better code.